# Extract specific number from command outout

Tags: grep

I have the following issue.

In a script, I have to execute the `hdparm` command on `/dev/xvda1` path.
From the command output, I have to extract the MB/sec values calculated.

So, for example, if executing the command I have this output:

```
/dev/xvda1:
 Timing cached reads:   15900 MB in  1.99 seconds = 7986.93 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 478 MB in  3.00 seconds = 159.09 MB/sec
```

I have to extract 7986.93 and 159.09.

I tried:

1. `grep -o -E '[0-9]+'`, but it returns to me all the six number in the output
2. `grep -o -E '[0-9]'`, but it return to me only the first character of the six values.
3. `grep -o -E '[0-9]+$'`, but the output is empty, I suppose because the number is not the last character set of outoput.

How can I achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the *last* number, you can add a `.*`  in front, that will match as much as possible, eating away all the other numbers. However, to exclude that part from the output, you need GNU grep or pcregrep or sed.

```
grep -Po '.* \K[0-9.]+'
```

Or

```
sed -En 's/.* ([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using awk to just print the fields you want rather than matching on numbers. This will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ hdparm whatever | awk 'NF>1{print $(NF-1)}'
7986.93
159.09
```