# Format output of grep plus regex bash shell

Tags: bash, format

I have this situation.

In my script, I have to use the `hdparm` command on specific partion and extract the `MB/s` value calculated.

I'm able to achieve this thanks the us of grep and regex; so, if with

```
sudo hdparm -tT /dev/xvda1
```

the output is:

```
/dev/xvda1:
 Timing cached reads:   12596 MB in  1.99 seconds = 6320.55 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 594 MB in  3.01 seconds = 197.12 MB/sec
```

with

```
sudo hdparm -tT /dev/xvda1 | grep -Po '.* \K[0-9.]+'
```

the results are:

```
6320.55
197.12
```

Now, the next request is to print data in a different way.
The desired output is:

```
/dev/xvda1: 6320.55 MB/sec, 197.12 MB/sec
```

But I don't know how to obtain this; summarizing, what is requested is to print the partion and, in a single line, the MB/s values extracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68770342/6770384) was an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/374558).
If you want to append `MB/sec` anyways there is no need to remove it in the first place. Extracting `6320.55 MB/sec` would have been a lot easier than extracting just `6320.55`.

Anyways, an `awk` script is probably the best solution here:

```
awk -F' = ' '{a[NR]=$NF} END {printf "%s %s, %s\n", a[1], a[2], a[3]}'
```

If you don't need exactly that format, the script can be simplified to:

```
awk -F' = ' '{printf "%s ", $NF}'
```

which prints `/dev/xvda1: 6320.55 MB/sec 197.12 MB/sec` .

Comment: Hi Socowi, I tried both your proposals.

The first one works and print only the first MB/s value, which is the 'Timing cached reads'. So, no problem for me here.

The second ends with following error:

'awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `%s '
         ^ ran out for this one'

Comment: @LucaSepe Oh right, I forgot a `,`. Thank you for the notice. The problem should now be fixed.